# Asp.net Timer and Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

Hi I have searched a lot on stack overflow to find suitable answer to my question but could not find it. I hope you guys will help me with my problem.

I have a web application which have two update panels.

1st update panel only contains a timer whose interval is only one second and it acts as count down timer.

2nd update panel is conditional panel which only updates when countdown is finished.

The problem I am facing is that when I publish my web application the timer does not seems to work right the page some how used to come at top (I assume it get refresh). On local host it works perfectly without any trouble. The code is given below for aspx file and aspx.cs file

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
    </asp:Timer> 
    <div class="form-area">
      <div class="clock">
        <p><img id="c-time" src="images/clock.png"/>Current Time 
           <span class="spanclass">
             <asp:Label ID="CurrentTimeLabel" runat="server" Text="Label">
             </asp:Label>
           </span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <p id="text">
        <asp:Label ID="Processing" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="FilterLabel" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />Time Left for list to Refresh
        <span class="spanclass">
          <asp:Label ID="TimeLeftLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and for aspx.cs

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentTimeLabel.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
        if (SecondsLeft > 0)
        {
            SecondsLeft--;
        }

        else if (MinutesLeft > 0)
        {
            MinutesLeft--;
            SecondsLeft = 59;
        }
        if (SecondsLeft < 10)
        TimeLeftLabel.Text =  " 0" + MinutesLeft + ":" + "0" + SecondsLeft;
        else
        TimeLeftLabel.Text = " 0" + MinutesLeft + ":" + SecondsLeft;
        if (MinutesLeft == 5)
        {
            FilterLabel.Text = "";
        }
        if (MinutesLeft == 0 && SecondsLeft == 0)
        {
           function();
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance. Looking forward for help

Comment: Do you have `<xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" />` in web.config? It gets added when migrating from .NET 1.1 and screws up your ajax. Also, there are ways of displaying a timer in javascript, without doing a postback every second.

Comment: I am using VS 2012 with framework 4.0

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ovidiu. Try it in javascript with jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function () {Counter() }, 1000);
 });

var count= 0;
function Counter() {
  count++;
  $('#testLabel').html(count);
}
```

Comment: yes this is the alternative i have implemented it. I was just curious why this is not working on live website? as on local host it is working perfectly :) Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What error do you get when running live. Dit you try debugging the java script code with developers tools in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a ScriptManager control on the page?